# Jacobi matrix with complex entries and optimization's orientation

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, jacobian

What can we tell about the direction/ orientation of an optimization if the entries of the Nx1 Jacobi-matrix (gradiant) are complex?

According to wikipedia: "if the Jacobian determinant at p is positive, then f preserves orientation near p; if it is negative, f reverses orientation." but this is only valid for real entries. Is there a similar thing for complex entries?

Comment: You can’t take the determinant of a vector (the gradient is a vector). Can you be more concrete about the domain/co-domain of the function?

Comment: For more infos on my function, you can check my other [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3152981/jacobian-of-a-skalar-function-with-multi-dimentional-vector-input)